# Contexts after Cell Grouping

Tags: contexts, cells

I'm trying to separate my document into cell groups, each with their own context (much like the style of code isolation described by the answer here: [Localizing variables within a Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15470/localizing-variables-within-a-manipulate/15562#15562)), but the I can't get the grouped cells to share a context, even though Notebook's Default Context is set as "Unique to each cell group."

I have a [simple example](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/31729120/Grouping.nb).  The linked notebook appears as a single cell group (when I look at the grouping bars along the right side of the window), but multiple calls of `Print[$Context]` yield different results.

It seems like, once a cell has been created, it's context doesn't change even if I adjust the grouping.  What is going on in the simple example I posted, and is there a way to fix these weird context differences/prevent them from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: With 8.0.4 on Mac 10.6.8 I find cell contexts changing whenever the grouping is changed. What version and platform are you using?

Comment: Oh, huh, does the above document print all the same or all different $Context numbers for you?  I'm using 9.0.0 on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should mention that I eventually resolved this confusion.  Fultz's answer (referenced above) said

> Separate the examples into cell groups. *You can use, e.g., Section or Subsection cells to do this*

I was thinking of cell groups merely as any cells joined by the brackets on the right-side of the screen, and I was manually adjusting the grouping.  This did not work.  Evidently, using `Section` or `Subsection` cells is the appropriate way to have Mathematica treat cell groups properly for variable isolation.