# Unwanted interaction between instances of a Manipulate function

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, scoping

The function `trajectory` below is defined in terms of `Manipulate` and calls the auxiliary function `soln`:

```
soln[f_, y0_][t_] := 
     y[t] /. First@DSolve[{y'[t] == f[t], y[0] == y0}, y[t], t] 

 trajectory[f_] := Manipulate[
      {f[t], Plot[Evaluate[soln[f, y0][t]], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> 5]},
      {{y0, 0}, -2, 2, 0.25}]
```

Consider the following two calls to `trajectory` in the same notebook:

```
 (* example 1 *)
 f[t_] := 1 - t^2
 trajectory[f]

 (* example 2 *)
 f[t_] := 2 t - 3
 trajectory[f]
```

After evaluating the two lines in example 1, if I then evaluate the two lines in example 2, immediately the previously displayed output in example 1 changes so as to use the output from example 2.

How can this unwanted interaction be prevented? I would strongly prefer:

- ***not*** to use different names for the function `f` in the two examples (using  `g[t_] := 1 - t^2; trajectory[g]` and `h[t_] := 2 t - 3; trajectory[h]` does prevent the unwanted interaction; and
- ***not*** to use a pure function directly as the argument to `trajectory` (using `trajectory[(1 - #^2) &]` and `trajectory[(2 # - 3) &]` does prevent the unwanted interaction).

In short, is there some way of doing scoping to prevent what I'm seeing?

**Relation to similar question** [Localizing variables within a Manipulate](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15470/localizing-variables-within-a-manipulate?rq=1)

I had seen that related question and the answer provided, namely, to use the setting Evaluation->Notebook's Default Context-> Unique to Each Cell Group. However, that is unsatisfactory here because (i) it would require putting a copy of the code for `soon` and `trajectory` into a separate group with each example invocation of `trajectory`; and (ii) even in that case, the code may well be copied by a user into a different notebook where it may be awkward to use the indicated evaluation option.

Comment: [DynamicModule](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DynamicModule.html).

Comment: You are using Manipulate as a function. This is not really how Manipulate is meant to be used. Manipulate should be self contained. If you want to test 2 functions, make a Manipulate with pull-up menu and select one of the functions. In your example, first Manipulate detected `f` changed and updated. You do not need to even make a new manipulate call to see the interaction. Just defining `f` again in the global context will cause the Manipulate to change.

Comment: No, 2 or even half a dozen or more "test" functions would not suffice for building into the `Manipulate`: the idea is to create a function `trajectory` that can be used with *any" vector field function the user might wish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `trajectory[f]` passes the **`Symbol`** `f` to `Manipulate`, so that the `Manipulate` updates to the new `f` whenever the definition of `f` is changed.  The trick is to somehow to evaluate `f` so that the symbol `f` is replaced by its definition before it is injected into the `Manipulate` code.

Method 1:

```
ClearAll[soln];
soln[f0_, y0_] := Function[t0, 
  y[t0] /. First@DSolve[Evaluate@{y'[t] == f0[t], y[0] == y0}, y, t] // Evaluate]

trajectory[f0_] := With[{f = Function[t, Evaluate@f0[t]]},
  Manipulate[
   {f[t], Plot[Evaluate[soln[f, y0][t]], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> 5]},
   {{y0, 0}, -2, 2, 0.25}]
  ]
```

Method 2:

```
ClearAll[soln];
soln[f_, y0_] := y /. First@DSolve[Evaluate@{y'[t] == f[t], y[0] == y0}, y, t]

trajectory[f_] := With[{sol = Evaluate@soln[f, #] &, ft = f[t]},
  Manipulate[
   {ft, Plot[Evaluate[sol[y0][t]], {t, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> 5]},
   {{y0, 0}, -2, 2, 0.25}]
  ]
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to simplify this so that a `Function` construct is not needed? The code is something I'd like somebody to be able both to use and to understand readily who is fairly new to using *Mathematica*.

Comment: In the first solution, replace `soln` by `soln[f0_, y0_][t0_] := y[t0] /. First@DSolve[Evaluate@{y'[t] == f0[t], y[0] == y0}, y, t] /. t -> t0;` -- Would that be readily understood?  (There are real issues of scope here, which may not be familiar to somebody not acquainted with programming languages.)